# Row Order in Python and abstraction to a Cartesian plane

Tags: python, numpy, row, iteration

How to translate the coordinate system of a 2D Cartesian plane (x,y) to a matrix with indexes a[i,j]?

Say you have to simulate heat conduction in a 2D plane using the Finite Difference method. You're given the boundaries of the system as a point in the lower left, `pos_inf`, and a point in the upper right, `pos_sup`.

The results form a surface map, where the index a[i,j] stores the value of the temperature of that point, and have to be stored in a matrix with indexes `i`, `j`, as `a[i,j]`. With the same spacing h for the both directions, how should the discretization be done, and how does the row-ordering that Python follows interferes with that?

Comment: Might be a good idea for you to formulate the post as a question, and answer it yourself. You might even get some answers from other users with good explanations ;]

Comment: This isn't "in python" it's in whatever NumPy object you have.

Comment: @Marcin: true, but the general idea holds for python lists as well

Comment: Congrats, you just recreated [numpy.meshgrid](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html). Also, not a question.

Comment: @Ivan: you might also be interested in trying `np.indices((5,6))`.

Comment: Junuxx, I think you misunderstood the objective of this question. The objective is not to give the best code, it's to explain the principle behind it. Also I reformulated in question form.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget If that's true, then it's not specific to python either. It's just the normal layout of nested arrays (and array-backed structures).

Comment: @Marcin: Also true. I think this post needs to be properly restructured and reworded to be (1) a well-formulated question and (2) a well-formulated answer to that question

Comment: Any suggestions? What is the "proper" way to make this question?

Comment: Take out everything below the _"A:"_ and post it as an answer, for one.

Comment: I'm voting to close as "not a real question." Eric's suggestion for revising this question is a good start, but I think the question "Given a Cartesian plane, how to discretize it in a matrix form?" is still too vague. I think you should rephrase it about the best way to understand row-major order. If this is closed, I could see myself voting to reopen after substantial revision.

Comment: @senderle I thought if you participated in the close vote, you weren't allowed a re-open vote...

Comment: Ok, changed as a question for the problem. Also, if the question is closed, all the work in the answer is wasted until different persons decide that it should be reopened. http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions

Comment: @Ivan: Closed != deleted

Comment: @JonClements, I found the relevant information -- you're _almost_ right. You can indeed vote to close and then vote to reopen, but you may cast only one of each kind of vote. "[Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) can go through multiple close and reopen cycles, but each individual user may only vote once in each direction in the cycle."

Comment: The question is better now, BTW -- thanks for being willing to edit it.

Comment: After all the changes in the format of the question, it is still not good enough? Could some one in the closing votes point to what didn't follow the FAQ, so I can improve it?

Comment: Changed the question again, so a) there is a clear question relevant to an algorithm and b) a specific programming problem, and c) unique to programming profession. It is also specific, hopefully relevant to others, on-topic and I think that I've kept an open mind so far.

Comment: @Ivan, I will say that in general, questions posted with the intent of self-answering are often held to a higher standard than normal questions -- with good reason. That said, there are currently three reopen votes pending including mine.

Comment: Thanks senderle. I'm still pushing for this question to get an understanding of what is a good question to self answer and what is not. This process of closing and opening was a surprise for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After bashing my head for a while now, I finally got the grips with the difference with row-order that Python uses and the definition of coordinates in a Cartesian plane. It's simple, but I'm putting it here because it can be confusing for the novice or the dyslexic.

As it has been pointed out, this is very similar to the behavior of [np.meshgrid](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html). The reason of this question is to explain in plain words the idea of the conversion of a cartesian plane to a matrix form.

Given a plane with a point in the lower left, pos_inf, with coordinates pos_inf = (x_inf, y_inf) and a point in the upper right, pos_sup (x_sup, y_sup), a spacing h (that I assume it will be the same for the x and y directions), the number of discretization points in each direction is equal to

```
points_x = int((x_sup - x_inf) / h)
points_y = int((y_sup - y_inf) / h)
```

Let's say that I want to store the value of a function in each point of this grid. I generate a matrix with size

```
a = np.zeros((points_y, points_x))
```

Note that the rightmost index in Python, j in a[i,j], go through the elements in the the *same* line, points_x times. i, the leftmost index, will go through the number of columns, points_y. A for loop is given by

```
for i in xrange(points_y):
  for j in xrange(points_x):
    a[i,j] = i
```

This way the points in the direction x are correspondent to the j index, and the points in the y direction are correspondent to the i index. So, for example, if points_x = 5 and points_y = 6, a cartesian space discretized with h = 1, starting with x_inf=0 to x_sup=5 and y_inf = 0 to y_sup = 6, would be

```
a = np.zeros((5,6))
for i in xrange(5):
  for j in xrange(6):
    a[i,j] = i

array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
   [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
   [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
   [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.]])
```

This graph shows the directions:[image]